# django API Serializer : cannot update foreign key field : response is 400 Bad Request The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax

Tags: python, django, api, request

i am new to django API framework and i am getting response

> 400 Bad Request 
> The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.

Models.py

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Customer(models.Model):
    # customer related field
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name', 'product','color' )

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(many=False)
    
class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'product' )
```

Views.py

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()

Request data(POST Json)

{
     "name": "test", 
     "product": "1"
}
```

Comment: What are you using to send the data? If it's some code can you add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems:

1. Your `Product` model and `Product` serializer fields are not matching, perhaps Product serializer should have a field called `price` not `product`.
2. In order to create `Product` instance via post request, serializer needs more data than you are already providing.

An example request can be like following:

```json
{
   "name": "test", 
   "product": {"name":"product_name", "price":"1", "color":"red"}
}
```